# FuzzyRowFilter and IPC server unable to read call parameters: Error in readFields

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I am trying to use the FuzzyRowFilter. Im on Hbase 0.94.6-cdh4.3.0, on a Cloudera 4.3.0 cluster.

I got the java file from https://builds.apache.org/job/HBase-0.94/ws/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/FuzzyRowFilter.java , after following the link from https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-7628. I could not find 
the minor version 766 any more, so extracted the file from 0.94 trunk.

I have a test table which scans like this

hbase(main):005:0> scan 'test_fuzzy_rules'
ROW                                      COLUMN+CELL
 1XX_2XX                                 column=rules:rule1, timestamp=1375719501754, value=Value from rule1
 1XX_2XX                                 column=rules:rule2, timestamp=1375719535698, value=Value from rule2
1 row(s) in 0.0170 seconds*

And I set up my rule filter like below and associated it with a Scan object and HTable.

`FuzzyRowFilter fuzzyFilter = new FuzzyRowFilter(
Arrays.asList(new Pair<byte[], byte[]>(Bytes.toBytesBinary("\\x00\\x00\\x00_2XX"),
new byte[] {1, 1, 1, 0 , 0, 0, 0 })));`

When I run my job, I get the following error

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=10, exceptions:
Mon Aug 05 17:20:04 BST 2013, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable@556917ee, java.io.IOException: IPC server unable to read call parameters: Error in readFields

at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ServerCallable.withRetries(ServerCallable.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextScanner(ClientScanner.java:205)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.<init>(ClientScanner.java:120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getScanner(HTable.java:665)
    at xx.xx.xxxx.xx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx.xxxx.main(XXXX.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)....
```

Any idea what is going on here. I tried to trace the error but am lost.

Thanks
Regards